# POSTing using ajax is unsuccessfull

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

JS embedded in a php page called(check.php) as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function getSelected() {
        if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
        else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
        else {
                var selection = document.selection && 
                                document.selection.createRange();
                if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
                return false;
        }
        return false;
}
/* creating sniffer */
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content-area').mouseup(function() {
                var selection = getSelected();
                if(selection && 
                (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))) {
                alert('Sending the following text to the server via AJAX: ' 
                     + selection);
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url : "calculate.php",
                                data: {selection: encodeURI(selection)},
                                success: function(data, status){
                                        console.log(status);
                                },
                        });
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

at the calculate.php, I'm doing the following.

```
if(isset($_POST['selection']) && !empty($_POST['selection'])){
      $selection = trim($_POST['selection']);
}else{
      $selection = "no selection text received";
}
```

I'm selecting a text using JS and sending it to another php script which then inserts it to a DB. I'm getting the `alert` on selecting the text but the `$selection` variable in `calculate.php` is getting the value from else loop. I want to access the POSTed value which I'm unable to access at the moment. Please help me, I'm a complete beginner to these things

Comment: If everything else it's correctly working, see if you are sending a real value with your javascript code. maybe the selection variable it's empty and thus it doesn't enter in your if branch. please check what encodeURI(selection) gives to you or else do an print_r($_POST) in your calculate php and console.log(data) inside your ajax call to see what are you posting.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but I can able to achieve this using the PHP session variable.